# Creating custom text value for ListBoxFor

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

So my initial need is that I need to display two properties in the MVC control ListBoxFor. Basically I want to do something like this:

```
       @Html.ListBoxFor(m => m.ContractLocations, new SelectList(Model.ContractLocations, "CUSTNMBR", "CUSTNAME" + " - " + "CUSTNMBR" ), new { @class = "form-control row marb10", size = 15 })
```

But obviously it won't let me do that. So I am assuming that I need to create a custom property in my ViewModel? But I'm not really sure how to combine two strings within my model? Basically I want to create something similar to a ko.computed where it adds the two values together and then I can display it on my ListBox control. Although I might be thinking about this all wrong and maybe there is an easier alternative?

So what is the best option to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a list property to your model:

```
public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> ContractLocationsList { get; set; }
```

In your `Action`, build your list, something like:

```
myModel.ContractLocationsList = new List<SelectListItem>() {
  new SelectListItem() { Value = Customer.Id, Text = Customer.Name + " - " + Customer.Number }
};
```

And now in your `View`, you can simply:

```
@Html.ListBoxFor(m => m.ContractLocations, Model.ContractLocationsList, ...)
```

Notice that `ContractLocationsList` holds the list of values to select from, while `ContractLocations` holds the actual selected values.

Comment: Thank you Racil! I had to add some loops and such to add the necessary data but this is essentially what I was looking for. Thanks!